# How to pad days and months with zeros in a string

Tags: python, string, date

I need help with a program that can read a string representing a date value  (e.g., `'4/15/19'`) and produces a new string in which the month has exactly two digits, the day has exactly two digits, and and the year is a four-digit value.

For example, for input `'4/5/19'` the program outputs `'04/05/2019'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.strptime("4/5/19", '%d/%m/%y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(d)
# 04/05/2019
```

More formats [here](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).